# Postgres COPY output with double-quotes adding more than what is needed

Tags: postgresql, double-quotes, pg-dump

I'm attempting to dynamically create a script that gets saved as a bat file that will be scheduled to execute daily via Windows Task Scheduler. The script performs full database backups for each Postgres database using pg_dump.

The current script is as follows:

```
COPY (SELECT 'pg_dump '|| datname || ' > e:\postgresbackups\FULL\' || datname || '_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.dump' FROM pg_database) TO 'E:\PostgresBackups\Script\FULL_Postgres_Backup_Job_TEST.bat' (format csv, delimiter ';');
```

An example of the output is as follows:

pg_dump postgres > e:\postgresbackups\FULL\postgres_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%*%time:~0,2%*%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.dump

I need help with updating my code so that the output will include double quotes around the name of the dump file; however, when I add this to my COPY script it adds more than what is necessary to the output.  I would like the output to look like the following which includes the double-quotes:

pg_dump postgres > "e:\postgresbackups\FULL\postgres_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%*%time:~0,2%*%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.dump"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you change the format from `CSV` to `TEXT`?

Comment: How do you expect `COPY` to do a full database dump or run `pg_dump`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Mike Organek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72733503/postgres-copy-output-with-double-quotes-adding-more-than-what-is-needed/72736684#comment128471194_72733503), my issue has been resolved by switching the format from CSV to TEXT. Now when I enclose the dump filename in double quotes, the output is more of what is expected and works as intended. The only odd thing now is that in the output it creates a second backslash in the filename. My code has been updated as follows:

```
COPY (SELECT 'pg_dump '|| datname || ' > "e:\postgresbackups\FULL\' || datname || '_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.dump"' FROM pg_database) TO 'E:\PostgresBackups\Script\FULL_Postgres_Backup_Job.bat' (format text, delimiter ';');
```

An example of the output that gets created within the bat file is as follows:

```
pg_dump postgres > "e:\\postgresbackups\\FULL\\postgres_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.dump"
```

As you can see, it adds a double backslash; however, the `pg_dump` executes successfully!